# In-Place Upgrade with Netbox

Tags: upgrade

Is it possible to do a inplace upgrade of Ubuntu 18.4 LTS to the latest 22.04 with netbox installation? This is the first time i am doing the in place upgrade and i want to be sure that netbox and its dependance will not be affected by the OS upgrade

my theoretical strategy is to disable updates to net box and its dependances and only allow upgrades to the Ubuntu Operating System

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Ubuntu 18.04 has reached the end of its standard life. Thus, upgrading from it is a bit more complicated. The question about upgrading from an unsupported version has been answered before. Second, one step upgrade from 18.04 to 22.04 is not possible. You have to go 18.04 -> 20.04 -> 22.04, It may be easier to fresh install 22.04 now or 24.04 at the end of April '24.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Comment: It may be easier to do a full installation of the new system.

Answer (score 0):

Netbox has many dependencies, ALL of which may be "affected" by an "in-place upgrade" (which is actually a "reinstall of the OS").

All the dependencies like SQL, webserver, etc., must be replaced by versions that are four years newer. Trying to keep older dependencies won't work on a Debian-based system -- some of those older version will be incompatible with the newer OS.

The changes to your OS and dependencies might indeed break something in your setup. We have not tested Netbox. There is no certain answer to your hypothetical question.

Advice: Create a testing environment that mirrors your current setup. Use cloning or backup to make your changes revertable. Then test the reinstall on that environment. It will take time: That's the price your organization will pay for waiting almost six years.

I wish the answer were simpler or easier. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks user535733 for your insight and experience, appreciate your assistance...indeed have to implement a better maintenance strategy as well as a test environment